# ASP.net globalization not working on textboxes in live environment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to set us a multi-language site.  I have included on the web.config:

```
<globalization culture="auto:en-US" uiCulture="auto:en-US" enableClientBasedCulture="true" />
```

Also checked IIS but no luck

All conversion works on my dev environment Windows 8.1, but on the live environment textboxes are displaying the decimal digit as US "."  for South Africa instead of the "," they use as a decimal separator, strange enough labels and other display do convert accordingly.  Live environment is Windows srv 2008 R2.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Settings written in `Web.config` can always be overridden by a number of ways.

Lookout for other places wherein possibly globalization setting are being overridden.

1.)  Check first the Page directive of the page,

```
<%@ Page Culture="en-US" UICulture="en-US" Language="C#"
    MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>
```

Check the value of attributes: `Culture` and `UICulture`

2.) Search for any possible implementation of : `InitializeCulture()`
     method, this is a frequently used way to override culture settings at 
     runtime.
     Use `Ctrl+Shift+F` to search for this method in whole Solution. A 
     sample implementation of this method looks like:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        string value  = Request.Form["dropdownlist1"];       
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            this.Culture = value;
            this.UICulture = value;
        }    
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```

3.) Assembly attributes too are important:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("en-US")]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.MainAssembly)]
```

4.) I don't think there is any need to check `Web.config` settings
    on server(host) since you already override them in your website's 
    web.config.

5.) As a last check , may times developers use global.asax to set culture, something as:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Just a sample only...       
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =   
                               Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I checked and no other implementation was found and any other reference to culture equals neutral.  The puzzle is why textboxes  displaying decimals converts accordingly on my laptop local host but not when live on host server but display controls like label and grids do convert.  Which is why I think something is missing on the live that affects input controls.  I will continue to research and report findings.